# C# Publishing an event when subscriber cannot invoke the method containing the event

Tags: c#, events, delegates, eventhandler, subscriber

I have been working around with eventhandlers and have questions on publishing them to its subscribers.
So we have eventhandlers defined in the publisher as below

```
public event EventHandler<StateChangedArgs> StateChanged;

public class StateChangedArgs : EventArgs
{       
    public State CurrentState { get; set; }

    public List<Parameter> RToolStates { get; set; }

    public StateChangedArgs(State State, List<Parameter> rToolStates)
    {
        this.CurrentState = State;
        this.RToolStates = rToolStates;
    }
}
```

so in publisher's class, we have a method like below which triggers the event

```
public class StatePublisher : IStatePublisher
{
  public string SetState(int ..., string ...)
  {
   ...
   List<Parameter> rToolStates = new List<Parameter>();

   var State = GetCurrentState();
   **StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new StateChangedArgs
                        {
                            CurrentState = GetCurrentState(),
                            RToolStates = rToolStates 
                        });**
   }
 }
```

This method 'SetState' is invoked from a different application say ABC through interface.
Now, my requirement here is once this event is invoked, i need to immediately notify another output class say XYZ so i need to subscribe to this event from here. but when i do below from XYZ, StateChanged becomes null where we trigger an event in above code, obviously as SetState is been called from ABC and doesn't know that there is a subscriber in XYZ. Also they become two different instance so i will never get the desired results.

```
StateChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            State = args.CurrentState;
            rToolStates = args.RToolStates;
        };
```

I'm sure it is not always the case where subscriber will create instance of publisher and invoke the desired method like in my case the 'SetState'. But all the example code i have seen does that and i am not sure how to resolve in my case. the examples i have seen does this below

```
public class Subscriber
{
 Publisher obj = new Publisher();//obj will create new instance and so StateChanged will not get the desired results

 obj.StateChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            State = args.CurrentState;
            rToolStates = args.RToolStates;
        };
 obj.SetStates(..., ...); // here, my subscriber can't invoke this as that is not my requirement
}
```

Eventually, i will have two or more subscribers but how can i resolve this. Can i make the eventhandler as static? Will that work?

**Update**: The subscribers will not be shared, it will in the same application where the Publisher is present. Only thing is, "SetState" method will be invoked from ABC application and hence I want to know how to subscribe to 'StateChanged' that will give me the results when 'SetState()' method is invoked from ABC.

Comment: " a different application say ABC" - it sounds like you want to share list of subscribers between *two different processes (application)*. Please [edit] the question to make it clear whether it is the case. (Answer is you can't …)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Updated them. Is it possible that some other application invokes method in Publisher class that contains the event to be triggered and can it be listened from the subscriber class? if so, how?

Comment: I'm even more confused of what you have trouble with... So assuming you sorted out how another app calls "SetState" on a single instance of "publisher" in ABC process and assuming you have sensible subscribers in the process ABC that get initialized with a reference to that single instance of "publisher" (code in the post where subscriber *creates its own publisher* makes no sense to me, so ignoring that altogether) then your setup should work fine... Clearly something is a problem for you - but what exactly?